# Is review rich snippet on company level or domain level?

Tags: google-rich-snippets, trustpilot

In example, we have multiple domains; example.nl, example.de, example.fi, example.com.br. example.es, etc..

If we create a trustpilot page for our company and get enough reviews, would we be able to use the review snippet on all domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referring to rich snippets for SEO.

If you create a company profile for example.com on Trustpilot. Only example.com would be eligible for rich snippets.

It would be a weird experience for the user and also Google if you were collecting reviews for example.com and displaying them on example.fr.